# Send payload to specific client with Notification Hub

Tags: android, node.js, azure, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Azure Notification Hub Service. Now, the implementation can send to all client that register with notification hub. However, I can't send to specific person. I know [TAG Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx) but, the document said It seem a solution for specific group of same interest. Even it work for specific person also I want to know there is other way to send message to single client or not.

**The following code is payload and function to send message to client.**

```
var payload = 
{
    "data":
    {
        "message":"Notification Hub test notification"
    }
};
notificationHubService.gcm.send(null, payload, function(error){
  if(!error){
    //notification sent
  }
});
```

What I have done

> notificationHubService.gcm.send(**GCM REGISTER ID**, payload,
>   function(error){});

```
var payload = 
{
    "register_ids": "device register id"
    "data":
    {
        "message":"Notification Hub test notification"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the ***[Routing and TAG Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx)*** document:

*Tag expressions can contain all Boolean operators, such as AND (&&), OR (||), and NOT (!). They can also contain parentheses.*

This means that you can select the clients to whom you want to send the notification using *AND (&)* operation and      leave the rest using the *NOT* operation. Something similar that is given in the example.

notificationHubService.gcm.send('(tagA && !tagB)', {
            text1: 'Hello World!'
        }, callback);